# IOS локализация в Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, iphone, objective-c

Когда я пробовал локализовать `NSLocalizedStrings` в Xcode 3.2, он создавал папки типа en_Iproj и в ней .strings файл. В Xcode 4.4 при нажатии `add localization` в Project -> Localizations он просто добавляет в список язык и создает .string файл в InfoPlist.strings в результате вижу следующее:

[image]

Вопрос: в этой версии Xcode так это и делается либо я неправильно что-то делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> создает .string файл в InfoPlist.strings

И при этом кладёт этот новый .strings файл в папку с выбранным языком, всё верно.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!